# SCCM OSD - Standalone Media

Tags: sccm

I am trying to put together a SCCM standalone OSD build media solution which is based on our production Windows 10 TS. The production TS wipes the disk (existing Windows 7) and installs Win 10. The solution now works end to end as expected on a virtual machine however when it comes to a physical machine, I am running into a strange behaviour where in after configuring the HP BIOS (secure boot etc.) in WinPE, during the subsequent reboot, instead of booting into the staged Winpe from the HDD to continue with the TS, it once again boots from the Standalone media USB and starts the build process all over again.

The overall steps of my Standalone TS are as below:

1. Trigger the autorun TS exe from the running Windows 7 OS USB drive
2. Enter the password to start the TS
3. Select the only standalone TS presented
4. Disable bitlocker
5. Reboot (to boot image assigned to this TS)
6. Convert BIOS to UEFI (if it is not already UEFI)
7. Restart computer (to boot image assigned to this TS)
8. Partition disk in WinPE
9. Configure HP BIOS **** This is where it configures secure boot, bios password etc. Everything seems to be working as expected up until this stage

Below is the smsts.log snapshot at that stage:

[SMSTS.log snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW7Je.png)

At this stage I have also verified that the boot order is correctly set (as shown below)

[HP BIOS Utility Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5KLt.png)

10. Reboot (to boot image assigned to this TS)
    This is the stage where it starts all over again booting into the inserted USB and starts the standalone task sequence by prompting for the media password (of step 2 above).

Just wanted to know what I am doing wrong. Why is the TS starting all over again booting into the USB? I highly suspect, at the BIOS configuration stage, something happens at the BIOS level because of which, during the subsequent reboot, the HDD is not “visible” to the boot manager and hence falls back to the next boot order option which is the USB containing the standalone boot media.
Any thoughts? Is there anything that I can do in terms of the troubleshooting to know what’s happening?
Thank you.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, try removing the USB device once the initial Task Sequence has started, and then see whether the reboot at step 10 succeeds or fails.  If it fails, see if you can figure out why.  You might also consider skipping step 9 (the BIOS reconfiguration) to see whether that does indeed make any difference or not.

Comment: When I remove the USB, the boot fails with DOS-style prompt (with black background) with the message ">>Start PXE over IPv4". If I continue to boot into USB, and F8 and check the disk, there is C drive with bootmgt,bootmgr.efi files as well as sms flder, Sources folder (with boot.wim), _SMSTaskSequence folder ect. I can even run diskpart. With Disk 0 selected, I can see 4 partitions (system, Reserved,Primary,Recovery)

Comment: So the UEFI boot menu isn't showing you the hard drive as a boot option?  OK.  I only have limited experience with SCCM, but looking at your sequence of events, I suspect the problem is that your Task Sequence is repartitioning the disk and then trying to reboot back into the boot image.  All the Task Sequences I've seen only repartition the disk immediately before starting the Windows install.  Perhaps try reordering the sequence so that the BIOS settings are done first, then reboot, then partition the disk?

Comment: Another observation is that at the stage where it boots from the USB (as opposed to the HDD with the intended staged Winpe boot.wim), if I launch cmd with F8 and run bcdedit, I get the error "The boot configuration data could not be opened. The system can not find the file specified". It looks as though the boot process can not see the bcd store. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did SCCM actually recreate the BCD store after you repartitioned the disk?

Comment: I thought when you added 'Reboot Computer' TS step (to boot into the boot media linked to the TS), it automatically adds an entry into the BCDStore for us. In reality it should point to a boot  configuration present under C:\\_smsTaskSequenceFolder. And that's where the computer boots from during the subsequent restart. In my case the BCD store itself does not appear to be 'visible' to the BIOS/UEFI following the reboot. Looks like enabling SecureBoot which I do just before the reboot (through the TS using HP Bios config utility) shields it for UEFI from "seeing". Let me try without secureboot

Comment: Even disabling SecureBoot did not make any difference. It's a real mystery to me. The problem is the issue falls somewhere in between HP and Microsoft's territory so if i were to get technical support, I am sure they will try their best to palm it off to each other. To make it worse it happens at the WinPE stage so difficult for their support to remote in,

Comment: Have you tried postponing the repartitioning of the disk (until you are ready to install Windows) as I suggested earlier?